# Bounded element's ItemsSource is not updated in view

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a simple ListView What is bound to an object's (TaxonDescription) list.

**When I select another TaxonDescription, then the ListView's element are doesnt updated.**

Maybe I need somewhere the NotifyPropertyChanged, but i tried everywhere.

There are my classes.

At the page's codebehind I check the ItemSource, and it is have the right list element, just dont updated to the View.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Descriptions}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding ActualSelectedDescription, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DescriptionName}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>


// this not updated
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ActualSelectedDescription.Images}"> 
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding NormalUri}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding ActualSelectedDescription.Name}"/> //This is works well
```

The ActualSelectedDescription is changed by an event.

```
public TaxonDescription ActualSelectedDescription
        {
            get{return actualSelectedDescription;}
            set { actualSelectedDescription = value;
                  RaisePropertyChanged("ActualSelectedDescription"); } 
            //In the setter the Images are in the list
        }
```

And there is the list element in the *Images* list

There is the Description class, with the list.

```
class TaxonDescription
    {
        public List<BaseImage> Images { get; private set; }
                    public  string Name { get; private set; } 

        public TaxonDescription(string taxonName, string descriptionName)
        {
            Name = taxonName;
            Images = new List<BaseImage>();
            //Adding some element
        }
    }
```

Any accurate idea can help, i will try them all ;)

Comment: Is anything updating `ActualSelectedDescription`?

Comment: Yes, in the model the setter, getter is triggered. And the TaxonDescription have other properites, what is bound to a simple TextBlock, what is updated in the view.

I updated my example

Comment: I asked b/c I do not see anything setting a new value of `ActualSelectedDescription`. Is the setter called by anything? Is a breakpoint hit if placed in the setter?

Comment: Yesm it is hitted, and called by the another listview (see example) SelectedValue two binding.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39692/discussion-between-shawn-kendrot-and-krekkon)

Comment: Sorry, i cannot chat now. :(
I have to sleep, just try help with my last breath :D

Comment: What is a `BaseImage`? Perhaps it's not an issue with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Instead, it could be that your images are not in a recognizable format. Are you getting any errors in the Visual Studio Output window when you run your application?

Comment: No i checked, the output is not send any error about binding or anything. BaseImage is my class, That have NormalUri String, with NotifyPropertyChange

Comment: Krekkon, Have you verified that your image URIs are correct? How are you storing images within your app? As resources or as files that get copied to the output directory? What happens if just hard code one of the URIs in your view instead of using a binding, e.g., `<Image Source="real_URI_here" />`.

Answer (score 0):

`ActualSelectedDescription.Images` has no change notification.

Try adding notification for `Images` property.

If that's not possible, make `Images` an `ObservableCollection<BaseImage>`.

If that's an issue, try setting data context to a notifying property:

```
// this should start updating
<ListView DataContext="{Binding ActualSelectedDescription}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"> 
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding NormalUri}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

### EDIT:

Just noticed that `TaxonDescription` is not `public` - is that a typo here in SO or is the class private in your actual code?

Since if it's private, the `ItemsSource="{Binding ActualSelectedDescription.Images}"` will not work since there's no access to `Images` property.

Comment: Possbible the acces will be the bug, i will check your tip at night (10 hours to go :D ), Thank you

Comment: C# classes are `internal` by default, so unless `TaxonDescription` is in another project/assembly, this shouldn't matter. Also, according to the OP, `ActualSelectedDescription.Name` *does* work. So, I don't think that's the problem.